# Is my proof of $\neg (f(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x)) \land (f(x) = x) $ correct?

Tags: calculus, functions, logic, solution-verification, inverse-function

**Theorem:** $$ f(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x) \implies f(x) = x, \ \ f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $$

---

**Proof:**

$f(x)$ is a real, continuous function that satisfies $f(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x)$.

That means that either $f : [x,f(x)] \to [f(x), f^{-1}(x)]$ or $f : [f(x),x] \to [ f^{-1}(x), f(x)]$. This is because the function is strictly monotonic, since it has an inverse.

This interval mapping shows us that $f(x) - x = f^{-1}(x) - f(x)$, which means $2f(x) -x = f^{-1}(x)$, yielding the equality:

$$f(f(x))  = 2f(x) -x$$

From that, we gather some info about the function itself:

$$f(x) = 2x - f^{-1}(x) $$

This leads to the fact of $f(f(x) -2x) = x$, with the consequence of:

$$f(f(f(f(f(x) -2x)))) = f(f(x) -2x) = x$$

This can only be true if $f(x) = x$.

---

**EDIT:**

The above proof has been edited a lot. In the first revision, I added a vital component I had forgotten. However, the revised proof was still incorrect, although the conclusion was correct. I have now reworked the proof quite drastically, and I believe it is correct.

Comment: Doesn't the identity function satisfy this?

Comment: It's not clear what constraints on $f$ beside $f^2=f^{-1}$ you're assuming that rule out options such as $f(x)=zx$ with $z\in\Bbb C,\,z^3=1$.

Comment: I also don't see the "which finally means $-x=f^{-1}(x)$" line.

Comment: Also, $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ does not imply that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: You really need to specify your domain here, too. You implicitly assume that $f()$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ (and you should understand where); it's not true over finite groups (take $f(x)=x+1$ in $C_3$) and it's not true over the complex numbers (take $f(x)=e^{2i\pi/3}x$). It's not even true over the reals without continuity; just take $f()$ to be the identity on integers, say, and let it cycle the open segments between integers appropriately.

Comment: Note that, for a general continuous function, 
$
f([a,\,b]) \neq [f(a),\,f(b)]
$.
Take $f(x):= x^2$ and $[-1,1]$ as an example. Is there something about the inverse property that means $f([x,\, f(x)]) = [f(x), f(f(x))]$?

Comment: $|f(x) - x| = |f^{-1}(x) - f(x)| \nRightarrow -x=f^{-1}$. E.g. $|5-2| = |8-5|$, but $-2 \neq 8$

Comment: Here he means that $f(x) \neq \ x \forall x$ , or the proof wouldn't make sense.

Comment: what about $ f(x) = \frac{-1}{x+1} \; ? \; \;$  If you want to rule this out based on the asymptote at $x = -1,$ you need to discuss the domain, somehow

Comment: @Randall I think I see why. $f(x)$ **cannot** equal $f^{-1}(x)$, because that would mean $f(x) = x$, which would mean $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't exist. However, technically, $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ is thus a contradiction, which in classical logic implies everything, including $f(x) = x$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $f([a,b]) = [c,d] \implies b-a = d-c$? That's not true of most functions.

Comment: @aschepler How so? If there's a one-to-one mapping between all points in $[a,b]$ to all points in $[c,d]$. That means that the intervals are "equally long", or $b-a = d-c$. I am a bit wary of this though, as we're dealing with infinity here, so the quite classical notion of length may not be applicable to the interval.

Comment: If $f(x) = 2x$, then $f([0,2]) = [0,4]$. In fact, any function which does satisfy $f(b)-f(a) = b-a$ for all real $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$ must have the form $f(x) = x + C$ for some constant $C$ (since $f(x) - f(0) = x - 0$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)-f(x)=0-x$ for $x<0$).

Answer (score 2):

As other people have mentioned in the comments, there are several issues with the clarity of your proof. It can be assumed that by $f(x)$ is a function, you mean a continuous real valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\to S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. I will continue under this assumption.

At the beginning of the second paragraph you are making an unjustified step. Why would $[x,f(x)]$ map to $[f(x),f^{2}(x)]=[f(x),f^{-1}(x)]$? There is a property of $f$ you are trying to use implicitly, but confused slightly:

> that property is that continuous functions with an inverse are monotone

From this you should be able to directly derive some inequalities that show that $f(x)=x.$

Hope this helps.

P.S. It might also help to think of your conditions as saying that
$f^3(x)=x$ AND $f$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

well, no. $$ f(x) = \frac{-1}{x+1} $$

function composition for Moebius transformations is nothing more complicated then matrix multiplication.

Take
$$
P = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$
P^3 = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
-1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
which gives the identity function $ \frac{-x}{-1} $